# Проблема с чтением RSS

Tags: php, rss

такая проблема, есть php-скрипт, который парсит данные из RSS на мой сайт.

```
function getFeed($feed_url) 
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);

    try {
        $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
        $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

        echo "<center style='color:red; margin:-5px 0;'><h3>" . $x->channel->title . "</h3></center>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
            echo    "<li>
                        <a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a><br>
                        <b style='color:#ce0a8a;'>Дата публикации: <span style='color:#199104;'>" . $entry->pubDate . "</span></b><br>
                        <span>" . $entry->description . "</span>
                    </li><hr size='3' noshade>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo    "<div style='margin:5px 0 16px;'>
                    <b style='font-size:18px; margin:0 10px; color:red;'>Не удалось обработать RSS ленту. Возможно, вы ввели неверный адрес. Попробуйте ввести другой адрес.</b><hr size='2' noshade>
                </div>";
    }
}
```

Этот скрипт рабочий, но при скармливании ему ссылки на RSS, где присутствуют опечатки (например, вместо `&quote;` пишется `&quote,`) выскакивает ошибка парсинга.

Вопрос - как заменить все спец символы вида `&(...),`

на `&(...);` ? Доступа к редактированию XML файла, в котором опечатки, у меня нет. Но прочитать его нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В массивы $need и $repl добавляете ваши значения для поиска и замены соответственно:

```
$str = '&quote, текст &quote,';

$need = ['&quote,'];
$repl = ['&quote;'];

$str = str_replace($need, $repl, $str);

echo $str;
```

С помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$str = '&quote, текст &quote,';

$patt = '~(&\pL+),~';
$str = preg_replace($patt, '$1;', $str);

echo $str;
```

---

Шаблон соответствует подстроке, если:

1. подстрока начинается с символа `&`
2. за которым следует одна или более букв латинского алфавита `\pL+`
3. после которых следует символ `,`

Comment: а есть , решение, чтобы все символы так заменялись? или нужно каждый символ в массивы добавлять?

Comment: @assasin2 да, можно с помощью регулярных выражений производить замену. Я позже за ПК буду, допишу свой ответ _(со смартфона очень не удобно)_.

Comment: @assasin2 написал "на коленке", проверьте работоспособность.

Comment: Да, всё работает, спасибо большое. Если не сложно, можете объяснить, как расшифровать данное регулярное выражение:
$patt = '~(&\pL+),~';  ?

Comment: @assasin2 да, чуть позже буду за ПК и добавлю к ответу описание шаблона регулярного выражения.

Comment: исправил Ваш вариант, всё работает, благодарю

        $str = "&#039,текст&#039,";

 $regex = "~(&[#a-z0-9]+),~";

 $str = preg_replace($regex, '${1};', $str);